# Why gen-idea stuck at 'lagom-internal-meta-project-cassandra' in lagom project

Tags: sbt, lagom, gen-idea

Could anyone please tell why while running sbt gen-idea with plugin 'addSbtPlugin("com.github.mpeltonen" % "sbt-idea" % "1.6.0")' stucks at creating the module 'lagom-internal-meta-project-cassandra'.

```
[info] Creating IDEA module for project 'lagom-internal-meta-project-cassandra' ... 
[error] Missing extra test configuration 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at 
org.sbtidea.Settings.logErrorAndFail(Settings.scala:11) at 
org.sbtidea.Settings$$anonfun$setting$1.apply(Settings.scala:16) at
```

Comment: (not really answering the question :-( ) If you are using IntelliJ I suggest you installed the [IntelliJ scala plugin][1] 
 instead of adding the `sbt-idfea` plugin on your project. The [IntelliJ scala plugin][1] provides support for SBT so that your changes in dependencies or project definition may be automatically picked up.


  [1]: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1347-scala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the meta projects are projects that don't have all the regular settings that a normal sbt project has. I'm not surprised that it doesn't work, but we never bothered to test with the gen-idea plugin because that plugin has been superseded by IntelliJ's own sbt support for several years, which is far better than the sbt plugin. You should use IntelliJ support, it's so much simpler, easier to use and provides a much better user experience.

Comment: Thanks a lot James.